# search for winforms datagridview

Tags: winforms, search, datagridview, full-text-search, search-engine

I'm looking to implement a search box for a datagridview control similar to let's say firefox Control-F which would bring up a search box and on finding a match the row would be highligted etc.

Is there any similar functionality perhaps using Lucene.net or similar ?

Note - this would be different than say DataTable.Search() as the # of columns are unknown and in some cases there are dozens of columns(over 100) !

Answer (score 0):

I would

1. Search in the datasource
   (depending on the datasource you use, there could be different ways: `LINQ`, `DataTable.Select()`)
2. Highlight or select the row in the `datagridview`

   ```
   myDataGridView.CurrentCell = myDataGridView.Rows[rowIndexFromSearch].Cells[0];
   ```